# PopupViewController returns null to ViewController

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I would like to pass datepicker.date from DatePickerPopupViewController to my SensorvViewcontroller which is shown below. However, it returns me "null". What am I doing wrong? My code is as follows:

```
#import "DatePopoverViewController.h"

@interface DatePopoverViewController ()

@end

@implementation DatePopoverViewController
@synthesize datePicker;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    datePicker.date=[NSDate date];
}



@end

#import "SensorViewController.h"

@interface SensorViewController ()

@end
// this represent my button which triggers popupViewController

-(void)chooseDate
{

    if([popoverController isPopoverVisible])
    {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        CGRect popRect=CGRectMake (900,1,1,1);
        //CGRect popRect=CGRectMake (tools.frame.origin.x,tools.frame.origin.y,50,50);
        popoverController.popoverContentSize =CGSizeMake(320,216);
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
        datepop=[[DatePopoverViewController alloc]init];
        NSDate *ali= datepop.datePicker.date;
        NSLog(@"%@",ali);
    }

}

   @end
```

[image]

Comment: You appear to be presenting the popover before creating it and then trying to get the date immediately...

Comment: @Wain, How it should be then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
    CGRect popRect=CGRectMake (900,1,1,1);
    //CGRect popRect=CGRectMake (tools.frame.origin.x,tools.frame.origin.y,50,50);
    popoverController.popoverContentSize =CGSizeMake(320,216);
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    datepop=[[DatePopoverViewController alloc]init];
    NSDate *ali= datepop.datePicker.date;
    NSLog(@"%@",ali);
```

Should probably be more like:

```
    popoverController=[[DatePopoverViewController alloc]init];

    CGRect popRect=CGRectMake (900,1,1,1);
    //CGRect popRect=CGRectMake (tools.frame.origin.x,tools.frame.origin.y,50,50);
    popoverController.popoverContentSize =CGSizeMake(320,216);
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

And you should setup a delegate relationship or a block callback so that when the user has actually selected a date a method is called and you can do:

```
NSDate *ali= popoverController.datePicker.date;
NSLog(@"%@",ali);
```

Or, better, the popover controller gets the date from the picker and passes it as a parameter to the callback method / block.

---

Something like (typed inline):

In the popover:

```
typedef void (^CompletionBlock) ();

@propertty (copy, nonatomic) CompletionBlock completionBlock;

 - (void)dateSelected {
    self.completion();
}
```

In the source controller:

```
self.popoverController.completionBlock = ^{
    NSLog(@"%@", self.popoverController.datePicker.date);
};
```

Comment: Actually in my viewDidLoad method , I initited already controller =[[DatePopoverViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePopoverViewController" bundle:nil];
    
  popoverController =[[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:controller];

Comment: Ok, so you don't need to create it again, you just need to setup a way for it to handle the date selection and pass it back to your source controller.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I have not still able to handle it. I am missing something. your answer clicked accepted answer already.

Comment: Quickest: add a property to your popover controller which takes a block (make sure it's a `copy` property). When the user chooses the date, call the block. In the block, get the date from the popovers picker.

Comment: Could you please write a small code in your answer above then I could able to figure out the terms.?

Answer (score 0):

This following code works:

//in header

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIDatePicker *datePicker;
```

//in implementation

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
[datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
[datePicker setTag:10];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverContent release];

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tempButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];//tempButton.frame where you need you can put that frame

-(void)Result
{

NSLog (@"Pciked Date%@", datePicker.date);
}
```